# React Native DateTimePicker throws error: date:'<<NaN>>' on ios devices

Tags: ios, react-native, expo

I get this error on ios devices when i open modal for changing date!

> Fix error: Invariant Violation:
> [5413,"RNDateTimePicker",21,{"testID":"dateTimePicker","height":34.5,"width":142.66666666666666,"alignSelf":"flex-start","date":"<>","mode":"date","onChange":true,"displayIOS":"default","enabled":true}]
> is not usable as a native method argument

```
 const [date, setDate] = useState(new Date());
 const [mode, setMode] = useState('date'); //for changing between time and date mode

 const onChangeDate = (event, selectedDate) => {
    // console.log('date inside onChnage: ', date);
    // console.log('Select Date: ', selectedDate);
    const currentDate = selectedDate || date;
    setShow(Platform.OS === 'ios');
    setDate(currentDate);
    // console.log('currentDate: ', date);
    let tempDate = currentDate;
    let sDate = tempDate.getDate() + '/' + (tempDate.getMonth() + 1) + '/' + tempDate.getFullYear();
    setIsValidDate(true);
    setDateText(sDate);
  };
```